# Is it possible to merge test coverage on sonarqube level?

Tags: unit-testing, sonarqube, automated-tests, integration-testing, code-coverage

For Java I know the possibility to merge test coverage results on build level by specifying the same path of JaCoCo reports (see [SonarQube: Multiple unit test and code coverage result files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650322/sonarqube-multiple-unit-test-and-code-coverage-result-files)). This might be transported to SonarQube.

But is it possible to make this on SonarQube level?

I mean from different build servers or different jobs build and test software and combine coverage results at SonarQube side (perhaps by marking the SW version or any kind of given label)?

For me it would be usefull to combine integration and unit tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to "amend" coverage to an existing analysis. You have to orchestrate your build pipeline so that all kind of coverage reports are produced before you actually starts the SonarQube analysis.

Comment: Yes. I have all in place, every job produces report. 
But I would like to merge those results at SonarQube level.

Comment: Just run the analysis with the list of reports. Like `sonar-scanner -Dsonar.jacoco.reportPaths=report1.exec,report2.exec` and they will be "merged".

Comment: Interesting. I will try to create Jenkins pipeline, where at the end stage I will call only this command, so the reports will be merged. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can combine the result of multiple jobs. You can create two coverage folders, e.g.

```
- coverage-unit
- coverage-integration
```

and use the resulting lcov files, e.g.

```
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage-unit/lcov.info,coverage-integration/lcov.info
```